# Package name is not getting displayed on the installation dialog of my pkg

Tags: macos, pkgbuild, xcrun, productbuild

I am creating a .pkg from other .pkg files. When I try to install the resultant .pkg i can only see "install" on the dialog box package name is not getting displayed on the installation dialog box. How can I make the package name appear on  the dialog box during installation?
Thanks in advance[installation dialog box image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJtIs.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Distribution.dist passed to the command productbuild as productbuild --distribution path_to_distribution.dist does not contain the title of the .pkg.
If title of the package is available in the distribution.dist under title tag then the name will be displayed on the dialog box during the installation of the package